# Targeting document.getElementById to sub templates?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I cannot get certain fields in a form to unlock. I have a javascript file that works on certain pages, but not on others.

I am using `document.getElementById` to target form fields to disable or enable them depending on certain inputs. It works fine on one page but not another. I have double checked all my ids and they are correct. Here is the javascript:

```
var pass2 = document.getElementById("password").value;
     if (pass1 == pass2) {

            //start profile
            document.getElementById("premium-text").innerHTML = "Congratulations! You have unlocked the premium fields!";
            document.getElementById("premium").style.background = "#d1fdd3";
            document.getElementById("premium").style.borderColor = "#019408";
             document.getElementById("description").disabled = false; 
             document.getElementById("fax-number").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("facebook-url").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("twitter-url").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("google-plus-url").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("linkedin-url").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("type").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("city").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("status").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("price").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("bedrooms").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("bathrooms").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("size").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("property-id").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("video-url").disabled = false;
             document.getElementById("featured").disabled = false;
```

The only difference in the pages is one has the form fields in the template (form ids are directly in `edit-profile.php`) and the other page pulls in the form fields from a sub template that has the ids in it (`submit-property.php` pulls form fields from a sub template `partials/templates/submit-form.php`).

What do I need to do to target the fields that are pulled in from the sub-template? The `id` gets pulled into the page source code so I assumed the `document.getElementById` would work fine, but it is not for some reason.

[On this page](http://dev-integrity.myuvn.com/edit-profile-2/) the javascript is working but not on [this page](http://dev-integrity.myuvn.com/submit-property/). You have to create an account to have access to these pages. The user is `test1` and pass is `testpass`.

The password to unlock the form fields is `QuL7eD`

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be in the javascript. Can you post your html or a link to the different pages?

Comment: @SpencerMay I updated the question with urls

Comment: Worked perfectly for me in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox. Firefox might help you in its developer console as it is usually quite explicit about what it doesn't like...which is quite a bit. Mine throws an error  `documentGetElement....is null` and hightlights `document.getElementById("fax-number").disabled = false;`

Comment: The fax field is not present at all on the page which does not work and the other later fields also appear not to be present for the script to be able to enable them. Apologies if I am missing something. I now realise that although the pink bit went green if I was not in Firefox that it had still not got the other elements in the HTML.

Comment: @Steve I just removed the fax field all together. That's why it doesn't show anymore.

Comment: Correction to previous testing - in Edge and Chrome the dropdowns are not enabled unless you refresh the page and drop the password in again. Then they become available to drop.

Comment: Glad you figured that out - now seems to work in my three browsers - perhaps I hit it at the point you were making the changes. Was about to check in Safari but you seem to have disabled the login. Firefox complained that the password was not in a secure https page but I am sure you know that. It said Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.[Learn More]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have same multiple ids. If you can post your code I'll be able to assist you better.

Comment: I added the javascript to the question now.

Answer (score 0):

I split the Javascript into two seperate files and that seemed to work. I can only assume this had something to do with the fact that there were different field ids on each page and when the document.getElementById ran and didn't find all the ids (since some were on a different page) that is why it wasn't working.

Comment: So perhaps in a way @ArunSharma deserves a plus one after all instead of the downvote he got, as he was kind of on the right track! If the element id isn't on the page, nothing else will fire as the JavaScript will drop out at that point.